# Как воспроизвести 2 и более звука в PyAudio?

Tags: python, аудио, pyaudio

Я хочу сделать функцию, которая будет играть 2 звука одновременно (интервал) и она работает. Мой код:

```
import numpy as np

def interval(self, freq1, freq2, dur):
    t = np.linspace(0, dur, int(44100 * dur), endpoint=False)
    sound_wave = makewave(freq1, t)
    sound_wave2 = makewave(freq2, t)
    ddata1 = np.fromstring(sound_wave, np.int16)
    ddata2 = np.fromstring(sound_wave2, np.int16)
    newdata = (ddata1 * 0.5 + ddata2 * 0.5).astype(np.int16)

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1,
                rate=88200,
                output=True)

    stream.write(newdata.tobytes())

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()

    p.terminate()
```

Делаю по аналогии функцию, которая будет играть 3 звука одновременно (аккорд), и уже белый шум:

```
def fifth(self, freq1, freq2, dur):
    t = np.linspace(0, dur, int(44100 * dur), endpoint=False)
    sound_wave = makewave(freq1, t)
    sound_wave2 = makewave(freq2, t)
    sound_wave3 = makewave(freq3, t) # это добавлено
    ddata1 = np.fromstring(sound_wave, np.int16)
    ddata2 = np.fromstring(sound_wave2, np.int16)
    ddata3 = np.fromstring(sound_wave3, np.int16) # это добавлено
    newdata = (ddata1 * 0.5 + ddata2 * 0.5 + ddata3 * 0.5).astype(np.int16) # это изменено

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1,
                rate=88200,
                output=True)

    stream.write(newdata.tobytes())

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()

    p.terminate()
```

Код `makewave()`:

```
def makewave(freq, t):
    return 0.5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t)
```

Comment: Могу предположить что `ddata1 * 0.5 + ddata2 * 0.5` - среднее арифметическое тогда нужно писать `(ddata1 + ddata2 + ddata3) / 3`

Comment: Ну либо `(ddata1/3 + ddata2/3 + ddata3/3)`. Сейчас у вас явно значение переполняется.

Comment: Забыл скинуть код `makewave`, простите! Но все равно не работает, просто ничего не звучит.

Comment: Подождите, у вас там кругом дичь какая-то. У вас `np.fromstring` не ругается, что на входе не строка, например? Ну и определитесь, в каком диапазоне вы данные генерите. `makewave` делает данные в диапазоне [-0.5, 0.5], потом вообще работать не должно, а потом вы делаете тип `np.int16`, т.е. целые числа, а потом пытаетесь их проигрывать как `pyaudio.paFloat32`, т.е. `float32`. Вы уж определитесь, что вы за данные делаете, в каком диапазоне. Если это всё даже будет работать, то у вас там будут нули просто. Проще всего попробовать поменять `np.int16` на `np.float32`, но это не всё.

Comment: Я скопировал метод с интернета, я не особо понимаю, что там написано)))

Comment: А вот надо разобраться. Копипастить код, не понимая, что же он делает - это бесполезное занятие. Разберитесь. Там ничего сложного. Начните с того, какой диапазон значений у функции синус. Напечатайте, что у вас в каждой из переменных получается, из какого диапазона значения. Так постепенно и разберётесь.